# Where to find debug output from SD driver?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, debug

I have trouble with some SD Cards so I enabled debug output from SD driver with `sd_debug=on` in `/boot/config.txt`. I have looked with `journalctl` and checked the files in `/var/log` and in `/tmp` but cannot find any debug information.

Where to find the debug output from SD driver?

Comment: I believe you might need to use `dtparam=sd_debug=on` instead. If that doesn't change anything, check `sudo vcdbg log msg` to get logging information from the VideoCore, it might be output there. Posting this as a comment because I have not tested any of this.

Comment: @Hitechcomputergeek Thanks, that was it. With `dtparam=sd_debug=on` I get the debug messages. Please make your comment an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to enable this is `dtparam=sd_debug=on`. After putting this in `config.txt`, debug information from the SD driver should show up in `dmesg`.